# Resource not gets committed into svn repository, even if it is non-conflict file

Tags: java, svn, eclipse-juno

I have to do merge my dev-branch into trunk, if I do the merge process in eclipse, not able to merge some of the resources into trunk from branch. Some of them get conflicts, even if these are resolved in my working copy, while try to get commit into SVN repository, it gets fail. Please help me out, if anybody having experience about this. The error message i am getting like operation failed due to conflicts remained in xxxx.java, even if it is non-conflict file.
 Displaying the operation failed dialog box is below:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to first update and then commit? Update is necessary.

Comment: The project has been in up to date, and now I'm trying to commit the merged files.

Comment: how does this have anything to do with google-app-engine ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you marked the concerned file as resolved using `svn resolved <filename>` ?